# Doubts about the \input command use

Tags: input

Could I use the \input command syntax, in Minimum Working Exemple (MWE) as follow?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

   \input{../equation/eq_01.tex}

\end{document}
```

Otherwise what would be the similar or equivalent form to use this command?

Comment: In general yes. But beware of spaces or underscores in file names.

Comment: Yes, did you try something that failed?

Comment: I tested this MWE here, and the Miktex returned the error "File '../equation/eq_01.tex' not found.", being that the file 'eq_01.tex' is into the 'equation' subdirectory. What would one be happening?

Comment: the document as posted above will give an error about `\begin{documment}` typo, otherwise it should work unless you have security settings set to ban paths starting with `../`   are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: The path should be relative to the main *.tex document. In other words, if `yourdocument.tex` is in folder `mydocs/master/`, then the input file needs to be in folder `mydocs/equation/`. Is that the case?

Comment: @user139954 yes, it is the case. ´equation´ folder is inside of main directory, where is the main *.tex file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default reading files but not writing is allowed with paths starting with `../` however it is possible to install tex with tighter security setting such that no access to `../` is allowed.

If the current directory has

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

   \input{../equation/eq_01.tex}

\end{document}
```

and ../equation/eq_01.tex has

```
\[1=2\]
```

Then by default pdflatex on the first file will run without error producing a terminal output of

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./zz1.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file zz1.aux.
(../equation/eq_01.tex) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/u
pdmap/pdftex.map}] (./zz1.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1
/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on zz1.pdf (1 page, 9017 bytes).
Transcript written on zz1.log.
```

Note the path to the input file.

However to check things are working first try the easier (and more secure) case where the `equation` folder is a subfolder of the current folder and so the main file looks like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

   \input{equation/eq_01.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or even having the input file in the same directory as the main tex file.